# Optional CodeIgniter Routing Parameter With Dynamic Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest, url-rewriting, routes

Hi How can I add optional parameter for routing on code igniter php

`$route['api/v1/(:any)'] = "$1/index";`

`$route['api/v1/(:any)/(:any)'] = "$1/index/$2";`

The  url for example:

app.domain.com/api/v1/users call `$users->index()`

app.domain.com/api/v1/users/1 call `$users->index(1)`

I need tge route is dynamic `$route['api/v1/(:any)']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need the "users" can be dynamic. I already created a routes and it work for me can you check if this is the best way.

`$route['api/v1/(:any)/([a-z 0-9~%.:@_\-]+)/(:any)'] = "$1/index/$2/$3";`

`$route['api/v1/(:any)/(:num)'] = "$1/index/$2";`

`$route['api/v1/(:any)'] = "$1/index";`

Thanks